# java ssl tcp connection ok but data received to server is incorrect

Tags: java, ssl, tcp, x509

My problem is that I have ssl connection between java iso client and test server. Connection is ok, no problems with handshake, but server receives incorrect data.

As I see in log server receives just partial data during one read operation and some strange data also present in inputstream - maybe it is related to certificate information.

Note that without ssl this client and server works without any problems. Also when I create jks standart certificate simple by java keyTool everything is ok and problem not happen.

But when I work with x509 problems happens no matter if I send certificate as parameter for  server jvm by generating jks from cmd or use code below to generate jks in code. Connection and handshake always ok, but data in inputstream is broken.

This how I get certificate using boucycastle library. Almost the same for client and server

```
private SSLServerSocketFactory handleCertificate() throws KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    PEMReader pr = new PEMReader(new FileReader("p.pem"));
    X509CertificateObject cert = (X509CertificateObject) pr.readObject();

    PEMReader pr2 = new PEMReader(new FileReader("klient.cer"));
    X509CertificateObject cert2 = (X509CertificateObject) pr2.readObject();

    PEMReader kr = new PEMReader(new FileReader("001.key"),
            new PasswordFinder() {
                public char[] getPassword() {
                    return "password".toCharArray();
                }
            });

    KeyStore trustKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    trustKeys.load(null, "".toCharArray());
    trustKeys.setCertificateEntry("1", cert);

    KeyStore ksKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ksKeys.load(null, "password".toCharArray());
    ksKeys.setCertificateEntry("1", cert2);

    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSAPrivateCrtKey key;
    Object PK = kr.readObject();

    if (PK instanceof KeyPair) {
        key = (JCERSAPrivateCrtKey) ((KeyPair) PK).getPrivate();
    } else {
        key = (JCERSAPrivateCrtKey) PK;
    }

    ksKeys.setKeyEntry("1", key, "password".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] { cert2 });

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ksKeys, "password".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(trustKeys);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

    SSLServerSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
    return factory;
}
```

Code of server :

```
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            int size = 0;
            String mess_length = "";
            byte[] lenbuf = new byte[4];
            if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                socket.getInputStream().read(lenbuf);
                mess_length = new String(lenbuf);
                log.debug("Lenth of received message: " + mess_length);
            }
            int responseSize = 0;
            try {
                responseSize = Integer.valueOf(mess_length);
                size = responseSize;
            } catch (Exception int_e) {
                log.debug("Error of message lenth numbering: ", int_e);

            }
            byte[] buf = new byte[size];
            if (socket.isConnected() && socket.getInputStream().read(buf) == size) {
                log.debug("Message received.");
            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            if ("echo".equals(EnvironmentProperties.getMode())) {
                log.info("responsing in echo mode");
                log.debug("Data to send from server: {} in connection id={}", new String(buf,
                        "UTF-8"), uuid);
                out.write(buf);
            }
            out.flush();
            bytesSet.clear();
            log.info("responded");
```

log from server:

```
    17:37:26.166 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Mess
    age received.
    17:37:26.166 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onsing in echo mode
    17:37:26.166 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Data
     to send from server:  in connection id=ee7f73ac-6be9-4e7b-876f-35d31845d69e
    17:37:26.166 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onded
    17:37:26.166 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Lent
    h of received message: 200r
    17:37:26.167 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - :
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "200r"
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[na:1
    .8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
            at ru.billing.tcpipServerDummy.app.server.ConnectionCallable.call(Connec
    tionCallable.java:87) [TcpipServerDummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at ru.billing.tcpipServerDummy.app.server.ConnectionCallable.call(Connec
    tionCallable.java:1) [TcpipServerDummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_05]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na
    :1.8.0_05]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [n
    a:1.8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_05]
    17:37:26.167 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Mess
    age received.
    17:37:26.167 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onsing in echo mode
    17:37:26.167 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Data
     to send from server:  in connection id=ee7f73ac-6be9-4e7b-876f-35d31845d69e
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onded
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Lent
    h of received message: 4♦А
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - ╬°шс
    ър яЁхюсЁрчютрэш  фышэ√ ёююс∙хэш :
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4♦А "
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[na:1
    .8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
            at ru.billing.tcpipServerDummy.app.server.ConnectionCallable.call(Connec
    tionCallable.java:87) [TcpipServerDummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at ru.billing.tcpipServerDummy.app.server.ConnectionCallable.call(Connec
    tionCallable.java:1) [TcpipServerDummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_05]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na
    :1.8.0_05]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [n
    a:1.8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_05]
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Mess
    age received.
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onsing in echo mode
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Data
     to send from server:  in connection id=ee7f73ac-6be9-4e7b-876f-35d31845d69e
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onded
    17:37:26.168 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Lent
    h of received message: ┴А 2
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - ╬°шс
    ър яЁхюсЁрчютрэш  фышэ√ ёююс∙хэш :
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "┴А 2"
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[na:1
    .8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
            at ru.billing.tcpipServerDummy.app.server.ConnectionCallable.call(Connec
    tionCallable.java:87) [TcpipServerDummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at ru.billing.tcpipServerDummy.app.server.ConnectionCallable.call(Connec
    tionCallable.java:1) [TcpipServerDummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_05]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na
    :1.8.0_05]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [n
    a:1.8.0_05]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_05]
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Mess
    age received.
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onsing in echo mode
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Data
     to send from server:  in connection id=ee7f73ac-6be9-4e7b-876f-35d31845d69e
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onded
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Lent
    h of received message: 1194
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - ╧Ёхю
    сЁрчютрээр  фышээр ёююс∙хэш : 1194
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] INFO  r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - resp
    onsing in echo mode
    17:37:26.169 [pool-1-thread-13] DEBUG r.b.t.app.server.ConnectionCallable - Data
     to send from server: 6817121021052420000000000000000100000730173724000048001121
    101581111310001749439  749138         00809203123643













                     in connection id=ee7f73ac-6be9-4e7b-876f-35d31845d69e
```

Comment: Do you mind telling us more about the OS of your client and server? Do server and client run on the same system?

Comment: Client and server run on Win7 on localhost. JVM 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual problem. You're ignoring the result returned by `read()` at one point and assuming it fills the length buffer, and then if the next read doesn't return exactly that number of bytes you're ignoring the bytes actually returned as well. You need to store the result returned by `read()` into a variable, and:

- test it for -1, indicating end of stream
- otherwise keep looping until you get an entire message, however that's defined in your application protocol.

Other problems:

- The `Socket.isConnected()` test here is pointless. It won't magically become false if the peer disconnects. You have to detect that by getting -1 from `read()`, `null` from `readLine(),` etc.
- Ditto the `socket == null` test. It already must be non-null otherwise you would have thrown an NPE in `socket.getOutputStream().`
- You're creating a new `BufferedOutputStream` every time. You should use one for the life of the socket.